# Teamcity silently failing to deploy build artifacts to artifactory

Tags: teamcity, artifactory, teamcity-9.0

I have many teamcity jobs that deploy various things to artifactory. I've got teamcity 9.1.3 and two artifactory servers, a 4.3.2 and a 2.6.5. My build logs have no errors, when I click 'test connection' on either of my teamcity artifactory 'configurations' it says 'Success' and nothing indicates that anything is amiss except that, when I check artifactory, my artifacts are either absent or have not been updated depending on whether they existed previously. What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two things that have fixed this for me so far:

1. Copy your build configuration and delete the old one. Something about the copy process makes teamcity fix whatever's wrong with your old build configuration.
2. If step 1 doesn't work, I just changed my MSBuild target to compile with visual studio 2015 rather than 2012 and my artifact is now publishing again.

I'll add more to this list as I come up with them since I suspect I'll encounter this problem again.